# Firefox dropdown option font-size not being rendered

Tags: html, css, firefox

I need to increase the font for the `<option>` of a `<select>` list. While this works easily in Chrome, in Firefox the only thing that is being increased is the selected option. My Firefox version is 50.1.0

Referring to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtew85vk/), I obtain the following different results:

**Firefox:**[image: Chrome result]

**Chrome:**[image: Firefox result]

```css
select {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

I'm expecting to obtain the same behaviour of Chrome also in Firefox.

Comment: In my Firefox it looks like it does in Chrome...

Comment: please check your firefox version buddy. its working fine in my firefox.

Comment: what version of firefox are you using ? in  my version  50.1.0 . everything works fine

Comment: My firefox version is 50.1.0 and i see it as in the screenshot...what else can be?

Comment: try using `px` instead of `%` or other values . see if it works

Comment: Have you added any plugins to firefox or changed any accessiblity settings?

Comment: More info needed! What OS are you using? Retina screen or not, zoomed in or not, etc.

Comment: It seems like Mac problem?

Comment: @MrLister it's a Windows 10, not retina, without scaled dpi

Comment: @Pete I only have Firebug without any particular accessibility setting (as far as i know)

Comment: @Mark I thought all 3 of my solutions worked for you, I updated as requested.

Comment: @zer00ne nope. Sorry if i disappeared but that's because of Xmas holidays. Anyway after further testing it's still unsolved. At this point I assume it's a Firefox's bug...

Comment: firefox 57.0.1 still has this issue.

Comment: Firefox 73.0.1 still has this issue.

Comment: It is still exists in Firefox  77.0.1 64bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in Firefox but still not fixed.

They said it was resolved, but the issue still exists.

Disable Multi-Process and it will work fine.

> How to disable Multi-Process: (from [LINK](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1191898)):
>
> Go to about:config. Search for "browser.tabs.remote.autostart". There may be multiple results. Set them all to false and restart the browser.

Bug Link:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022

Comment: firefox 65.0.1 (Mac OS) still has this issue

Answer (score 5):

After doing a little bit of snooping around I see that some people have reported this issue in newer versions of Firefox. I myself use the development version and I have the same issue as you.

This [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms) by the guys over at Mozilla is quite interesting in this regard.

There's a section on select box styling over mutliple browsers/devices, but your options look thin.

Normally CSS attributes like `-moz-appearance: none` can help but in this case I can't see a work around, I've seen reports of this being a bug in newer versions of Firefox, so fingers crossed it's gone soon. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, i've tried `-moz-appearance: none` without success

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

<del>I neglected to fully explain the method behind my madness, simply because I wasn't 100% sure my solutions would work because of some little known bug occurring in certain Macs on the fullmoon (as you can tell I use PC and am jealous of Mac's graphics.)</del>

Thought you had a Mac, my bad. Regardless, the solutions work.

When dealing with fonts and inheritance, we can naturally assume if we have a `body {font-size:16px;}` inheritance will cascade down to the rest of the elements like a comfortable blanket of 16px to everything. Form elements are neglected and by default do not inherit font properties by default. We can fix this by:

- Using the `inherit` value like in fix 1 or...
- ... inherit from a parent like in fix 2 or...
- ... directly like in fix 3.

---

This Snippet has 3 fixes, and one of them hopefully will work for you.

**SNIPPET**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 600 16px/1 Verdana;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
legend {
  text-align: right;
}
select {
  width: 6ex;
}
/* Fix #1
|~~~~~~~~*/

select#X {
  font-size: 2em;
}
select#X > option {
  font-size: inherit;
}
/* Fix #2
|~~~~~~~~*/

select#Y {
  font-size: 200%;
}
select#Y > option {
  font-size: 100%;
}
/* Fix #3
|~~~~~~~~*/

select#Z {
  font-size: 32px;
}
select#Z > option {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <h1>Font-size</h1>
    <h2>Select<br>
    Option</h2>
  </legend>

  <select id='X' name='X'>
    <option value="X">X</option>
    <option value="1">2em</option>
    <option value="2">inherit</option>
  </select>

  <select id='Y' name='Y'>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="1">200%</option>
    <option value="2">100%</option>
  </select>

  <select id='Z' name='Z'>
    <option value="Z">Z</option>
    <option value="1">32px</option>
    <option value="2">32px</option>
  </select>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Nor in `Firefox 64`.